# Java, MySQL: I save "Česká Třebová", but saved "?eská T?ebová" (from terminal all good)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

When I insert from terminal all good: 
`INSERT INTO towns VALUES (113, 'Česká Třebová', 22, "test", true);`

But when I manually save through JDBC:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a2b", "root", "root");
stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO towns VALUES (200, 'Česká Třebová', 22, 'test', true);");
```

...or persist object from Hibernate:

```
String townName = new String("Česká Třebová".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
townDao.persist(new Town(townName, CountryCode.AQ, "test", true));
```

...or with PreparedStatement:

```
PreparedStatement addTown = null;
String addTownPrepared = "INSERT INTO towns VALUES (1100, ?, 22, 'test', true)";
addTown = conn.prepareStatement(addTownPrepared);
addTown.setString(1, townName);
addTown.executeUpdate();
```

...I see `?eská T?ebová` at MySQL 5.5

I have in database many cities named like `Göppingen`, `Würzburg`, `Kolín` - problem not with all non-latin symbols.

========================================

I am under Lubuntu 14.04.

```
show variables like '%char%';

+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

In `pom.xml` I have

```
<integration-test.jdbc.url><![CDATA[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a2b?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8]]></integration-test.jdbc.url>
```

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE towns (
  id                  BIGINT            AUTO_INCREMENT      ,
  name                VARCHAR (256)     NOT NULL            ,
  country             SMALLINT          NOT NULL            ,
  source              VARCHAR (256)                         ,
  is_active           BIT               DEFAULT 1           ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Screenshot from Workbench:
[image]

Comment: you also need to set UTF-8 encoding in table column / table definition.May be this will help you http://cameronyule.com/2008/07/configuring-mysql-to-use-utf-8/

Comment: @Yagnesh My tables and columns in `utf8` - no problem when INSERT or SELECT from terminal (with non-latin characters like Č) - I think problem with JDBC..

Comment: Wait, you have `new String("Česká Třebová".getBytes(), "UTF-8");`? Can you try `"Česká Třebová".getBytes("UTF-8")`? Also, can you try with `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a2b?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8", "root", "root");

Comment: @RooMan Are you saying that `useUnicode=true` will work in certain cases where `useUnicode=yes` will not?

Comment: Have you verified that your Java source file is saved with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "Česká Třebová".getBytes("UTF-8") and PreparedStatement give me the same result.

Comment: Can you post the PreparedStatement code you tried? Are you sure you aren't doing any other raw `getBytes()` calls?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch added `PreparedStatement` code to question. In this code I do not doind any other getBytes() calls.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Thank you. One last thing to check, try changing `String townName = new String("Česká Třebová"` to `String townName = "Česká Třebová";` Also, if that doesn't work - try `String townName = "Fred";` to make sure your code is doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @GordThompson `file -bi RouteUpdateService.java` give me
`text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `String townName = "Česká Třebová";` give the same `?eská T?ebová`. With `Fred` all is ok - I have in database many cities named like `Göppingen`, `Würzburg`, `Kolín` - problem not with all special symbols.

Comment: Then it sounds like a jdbc driver issue, have you checked your jdbc implementation?

Comment: Another possibility would be that your source files where the town names come from (either Java source or external data) are in another encoding than UTF-8. That could lead to problems. You could double-check with Notepad++ to see how it's displayed (enable show special chars).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch From Maven I have `mysql-connector` `5.1.28`. Changed to latest `5.1.31` - all the same.

Comment: @MicSim I see in console debugging values - and I see correct `Česká Třebová`. It mean that input data correct.

Comment: I found answer, very simple. Sorry for your time - I need to be more careful. I have correct <integration-test.jdbc.url>, but I was needed to change <jdbc.url> :( Thank you guys for help, maybe this discussion be helpful for others people.

Comment: You do not know what you do in "new String..getBytes()" pattern. It is a classic bug pattern to create character lost and performance degrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with URL to database! Are you sure that you edit that URL that you think?

In my `pom.xml` I have:

`<integration-test.jdbc.url>`, `<test.jdbc.url>` and `<jdbc.url>`.

I need to be changed the `<jdbc.url>` from `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a2b` to **`<![CDATA[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a2b?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8]]>`**